# How do I access "results" when original ansible task uses with_subelements

Tags: debugging, ansible, stat, subquery

I am trying to generate a list of "views" and the "domains" in each view.
i.e.:
internal/baseserver1
internal/baseserver2
external/baseserver1
...
For each of the above, I want to check for the existence of a "regular" file on the remote host under a known directory inserting the above values into the list of files to be checked.  I am attempting to check the value of `isreg` for each view/host in the above list.

roles/default/main.yml

```
---
zone_dir: /var/named

zone_domains:
  - domain:
    name: "jlhimpel.net"
    hostmaster_email: "john"
    views:
      - view:
        name: internal
        hosts:
          - host:
            name: baseserver1
            ip: 192.168.1.20
          - host:
            name: baseserver2
            ip: 192.168.1.30
      - view:
        name: external
        hosts:
          - host:
            name: baseserver1
            ip: 343.22.56.237
...
```

roles/tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: Debug fqn zone path
  stat:
    path: /var/named/internal/jlhimpel.net.zone
  register: f
  become: true

- name: Display f
  debug:
    var: f

- name: Display f.stat.isreg
  debug:
    var: f.stat.isreg

- name: Debug symbolic zone path
  stat:
    path: "{{ zone_dir }}/{{ item[1].name }}/{{ item[0].name }}.zone"
  loop: "{{ zone_domains|subelements('views') }}"
  register: p
  become: true

- name: Display p
  debug:
    var: p

- name: Display p.results.stat.isreg
  debug:
    var: item.isreg
  with_items:
    p.results.stat
...
```

Output:

```
PLAY [dnsServiceGroup] *********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net]

TASK [pocDnsService : Debug fqn zone path] *************************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net]

TASK [pocDnsService : Display f] ***********************************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => {
    "f": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "stat": {
            "atime": 1582308757.2357316,
            "attr_flags": "",
            "attributes": [],
            "block_size": 4096,
            "blocks": 8,
            "charset": "us-ascii",
            "checksum": "b8e6ecf9a617314ed1e040b4cd72dbde3dc9753c",
            "ctime": 1581784999.833953,
            "dev": 64768,
            "device_type": 0,
            "executable": false,
            "exists": true,
            "gid": 25,
            "gr_name": "named",
            "inode": 18788348,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mimetype": "text/plain",
            "mode": "0640",
            "mtime": 1581784999.1509356,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/var/named/internal/jlhimpel.net.zone",
            "pw_name": "root",
            "readable": true,
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": false,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 406,
            "uid": 0,
            "version": "1161797691",
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "writeable": true,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": false,
            "xoth": false,
            "xusr": false
        }
    }
}

TASK [pocDnsService : Display f.stat.isreg] ************************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => {
    "f.stat.isreg": true
}

TASK [pocDnsService : Debug symbolic zone path] ********************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => (item=[{'domain': None, 'name': 'jlhimpel.net', 'hostmaster_email': 'john', 'views': [{'view': None, 'name': 'internal', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '192.168.1.20'}, {'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver2', 'ip': '192.168.1.30'}]}, {'view': None, 'name': 'external', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '343.22.56.237'}]}]}, {'view': None, 'name': 'internal', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '192.168.1.20'}, {'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver2', 'ip': '192.168.1.30'}]}])
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => (item=[{'domain': None, 'name': 'jlhimpel.net', 'hostmaster_email': 'john', 'views': [{'view': None, 'name': 'internal', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '192.168.1.20'}, {'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver2', 'ip': '192.168.1.30'}]}, {'view': None, 'name': 'external', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '343.22.56.237'}]}]}, {'view': None, 'name': 'external', 'hosts': [{'host': None, 'name': 'baseserver1', 'ip': '343.22.56.237'}]}])

TASK [pocDnsService : Display p] ***********************************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => {
    "p": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_attributes": true,
                        "get_checksum": true,
                        "get_md5": false,
                        "get_mime": true,
                        "path": "/var/named/internal/jlhimpel.net.zone"
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "domain": null,
                        "hostmaster_email": "john",
                        "name": "jlhimpel.net",
                        "views": [
                            {
                                "hosts": [
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "192.168.1.20",
                                        "name": "baseserver1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "192.168.1.30",
                                        "name": "baseserver2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "internal",
                                "view": null
                            },
                            {
                                "hosts": [
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "343.22.56.237",
                                        "name": "baseserver1"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "external",
                                "view": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "hosts": [
                            {
                                "host": null,
                                "ip": "192.168.1.20",
                                "name": "baseserver1"
                            },
                            {
                                "host": null,
                                "ip": "192.168.1.30",
                                "name": "baseserver2"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "internal",
                        "view": null
                    }
                ],
                "stat": {
                    "atime": 1582308757.2357316,
                    "attr_flags": "",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "block_size": 4096,
                    "blocks": 8,
                    "charset": "us-ascii",
                    "checksum": "b8e6ecf9a617314ed1e040b4cd72dbde3dc9753c",
                    "ctime": 1581784999.833953,
                    "dev": 64768,
                    "device_type": 0,
                    "executable": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "gid": 25,
                    "gr_name": "named",
                    "inode": 18788348,
                    "isblk": false,
                    "ischr": false,
                    "isdir": false,
                    "isfifo": false,
                    "isgid": false,
                    "islnk": false,
                    "isreg": true,
                    "issock": false,
                    "isuid": false,
                    "mimetype": "text/plain",
                    "mode": "0640",
                    "mtime": 1581784999.1509356,
                    "nlink": 1,
                    "path": "/var/named/internal/jlhimpel.net.zone",
                    "pw_name": "root",
                    "readable": true,
                    "rgrp": true,
                    "roth": false,
                    "rusr": true,
                    "size": 406,
                    "uid": 0,
                    "version": "1161797691",
                    "wgrp": false,
                    "woth": false,
                    "writeable": true,
                    "wusr": true,
                    "xgrp": false,
                    "xoth": false,
                    "xusr": false
                }
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_attributes": true,
                        "get_checksum": true,
                        "get_md5": false,
                        "get_mime": true,
                        "path": "/var/named/external/jlhimpel.net.zone"
                    }
                },
                "item": [
                    {
                        "domain": null,
                        "hostmaster_email": "john",
                        "name": "jlhimpel.net",
                        "views": [
                            {
                                "hosts": [
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "192.168.1.20",
                                        "name": "baseserver1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "192.168.1.30",
                                        "name": "baseserver2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "internal",
                                "view": null
                            },
                            {
                                "hosts": [
                                    {
                                        "host": null,
                                        "ip": "343.22.56.237",
                                        "name": "baseserver1"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "name": "external",
                                "view": null
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "hosts": [
                            {
                                "host": null,
                                "ip": "343.22.56.237",
                                "name": "baseserver1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "external",
                        "view": null
                    }
                ],
                "stat": {
                    "atime": 1582326121.0318115,
                    "attr_flags": "",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "block_size": 4096,
                    "blocks": 8,
                    "charset": "us-ascii",
                    "checksum": "5deeb57dfd80c5b264ab5ebff8af728b2a551860",
                    "ctime": 1582079607.5288289,
                    "dev": 64768,
                    "device_type": 0,
                    "executable": false,
                    "exists": true,
                    "gid": 0,
                    "gr_name": "root",
                    "inode": 25378368,
                    "isblk": false,
                    "ischr": false,
                    "isdir": false,
                    "isfifo": false,
                    "isgid": false,
                    "islnk": false,
                    "isreg": true,
                    "issock": false,
                    "isuid": false,
                    "mimetype": "text/plain",
                    "mode": "0640",
                    "mtime": 1582079607.4818277,
                    "nlink": 1,
                    "path": "/var/named/external/jlhimpel.net.zone",
                    "pw_name": "root",
                    "readable": true,
                    "rgrp": true,
                    "roth": false,
                    "rusr": true,
                    "size": 406,
                    "uid": 0,
                    "version": "2850301314",
                    "wgrp": false,
                    "woth": false,
                    "writeable": true,
                    "wusr": true,
                    "xgrp": false,
                    "xoth": false,
                    "xusr": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

TASK [pocDnsService : Display f.stat[].isreg] **********************************
ok: [testFedora.jlhimpel.net] => (item=p.results.stat) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "p.results.stat",
    "item.isreg": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for pasting such verbose output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task below

```
    - name: Display p.results.stat.isreg
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ p.results|json_query('[].stat.isreg') }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": true
    "msg": true
```